# what is the following regular expressions trying to match?

Tags: tcl, expect

what is the following regular expressions trying to match:
`expect -re "classType=(.{3})"`?
what does this `(.{3})`means in regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regular expressions, `.` matches any character, `{3}` is a suffix to make something be repeated three times (i.e., `...`) and the parentheses around it make it a *capturing* group. (That means that the matched piece of input will be available as `$expect_out(1,string)` afterwards.)

Answer (score 1):

The same as `(...)` --- three characters.